# Make window's taskbar blink for JavaFX 2 Stage

Tags: javafx-2

I had posted this in Oracle's forums but hgot no response, so I'm trying here.
Is there any way to make the window's taskbar for a particular stage blink?
I'm building an IM client, and I want the taskbar to flash when a new message arrives.
Using a Swing JFrame I could achieve this just by calling setVisible(true); but JavaFX2's stage is not behaving the same way. 
Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't test it on all systems but on Win7 if you run next app and change focus it will blink by calling `Stage.toFront()`

```
public class Blinker extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("i'll blink");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(new Text(25,25,"blink-blink"))));
        stage.show();

        TimelineBuilder.create().keyFrames(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                stage.toFront();
            }
        })).cycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE).build().play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Sergey, Thanks for your reply!. You know, that's not working for me. I'm running windows 7 64 bits, jdk 1.7, javafx jdk 2.0.2 32 bits. The idea would be that if the stage is iconified, the toFront() would cause the taskbar to blink, instead of bringing it to the front, right?
The only way I found to do this is,
`if (!isFocused()){
            hide();
        }
        show();`
So basically if the user is writing nothing happens. And if he's not then the stage is hidden and shown, which causes the taskbar to blink.
I'll keep your suggestion in mind for the future though.
Thanks.

Comment: I see, maybe it depends on windows settings :) Glad you find out working solution!

Answer (score 0):

I used the below and it works fine..

```html
if (! stage.isFocussed()){
stage.toFront();
}
```